# Isotope with multiple filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, filtering, jquery-isotope

I'm currently working on a page that has a filter effect using the jQuery plugin, Isotope. https://colab.aut.ac.nz/events-test/. Currently it accepts only one active filter and it functions as a tab.

I'm trying to find any solution that I so that It can toggle more than one filter but still has a similar isotope effects. My reference on achieving the tab filter is by using the jQuery codes on this page http://isotope.metafizzy.co/filtering.html

Any suggestion achieving this using codes for the plugin or any alternative plugin would be a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually isotope has a combo filter example http://isotope.metafizzy.co/filtering.html#combination-filters

And this is how you would add items: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/methods.html#additems

Comment: This is the answer what I'm looking for! However I already done the task using some workaround. 

Thanks a lot. I will be using this on my future projects.

Comment: Please add examples to your answer and use the links for reference only.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a comma to your filter a tags, eg:

```
<button class="button" data-filter=".on-campus, .off-campus">On and Off Campus</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I got your point. However,  I'm trying to implement two buttons pressed at the same time. Not necessarily to add new buttons with combination.

Comment: You mean so it adds items to the content area as you click the buttons? I'm not sure how you could press 2 buttons at the same time on a webpage.

Comment: Yup exactly, that's what I'm trying to achieve but t seems the plugin has no options to that. I'm not sure neither. Any idea or alternative how to to this or perhaps you're familiar on its list items version, if there's any?

Comment: @Jed - sorry for the late reply. If you just want to add the items to the list then why use Isotope at all? On your example you dont seem to be using the Masonry part of it anyway. Why not just create a bit of JQuery to do it? I dont have time right now but I can whip up an example later.

Comment: I end up using a simple `<li>` element for the toggle button with some jQuery codes to toggle the event list items. I really appreciate your help. Thanks a lot. Please keep helping others. Thanks man.